# How to have a custom date in SSRS chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having a column chart and on its horizontal axis I have date. I want to have custom way of displaying date. The month should appear only once with the date and it should reappear only when the month changes. Below is the snapshot of what I wish to do. The available date options does not have it, so I am assuming, will have to put custom formula. [image]

Comment: If you can get it to display at the bottom of every column now I would write and expression on the visibility where it hides it unless its the min date of the month.  =IIF(Field!Month.Value = Min(Field!Month.Value), True, False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS out of the box can get you very close. You can group your values on the X axis. Below is what that looks like in design mode. Notice the 2 rows in the Category Groups pane, off to the right. (Here one shows `<Expr>`, the other `day`).

[image]

The first row in this pane groups the second row. When you preview/run the report, whatever adjustments you make in the first row will show just below the labels along the X axis. *Preview at the end.*

Since you only want to show the month name abbreviation in the grouping, set the **Group expression**, and **Labe**l value to the following expression. This just gets the first 3 character from the month name for the given day.

`=Left(MonthName(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Fields!day.Value)), 3)`

Enter those using the Category Group Expression dialog (below). You get to this by clicking the down arrow on the `<Expr>` row above, and choose Category Group Properties...

[image]

[image]

Open the same dialog, but for the `day` row in the Category Group pane, and use the following expression for the **Label**. This just shows the day number.

`=DatePart(DateInterval.Day, Fields!day.Value)`

While still in that dialog, go to **Sorting**, and make sure `day` is being used. We don't want to sort by the day number, it will mix the months together (not good).

Adjust the Y axis labels the way you want (by thousands), add data labels, and formatting. In preview mode that report should look something like this. Colors will vary.

[image]

Now, the month abbreviations are centered in their group. I don't know if that is a big problem for you. Still, looks okay, it will work across more than 2 months, and still looks very presentable.

Hope this helps! May be a good start in the right direction.